# ¿Como agrego una imagen a cada metodo de pago en woocommerce?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, buen día, quiero saber exactamente en que página debo incluir la imagen, solo necesito el nombre del archivo para poder editarlo. Necesito que la opción de "transferencia bancaria" tenga la imagen de el banco, como el de PayU. Un saludo y espero su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo cercano a lo que pides es usando inline-block de CSS.

```
<label for="trans-bolitas">Transferencia Bancaria con el Banco de Bolitas <img style="display:inline-block;" src="img/imagen-banco-bolitas.png"></label>
<input type="radio" id="trans-bolitas>
```